# Scons - using custom preprocessor with scons cache

Tags: c++, python, scons, c-preprocessor, wave

I am currently trying to make a build system around Scons, which would use Boost Wave driver as a custom C++ code preprocessor. After preprocessing the code is compiled with MSVC. At the moment I launch wave for each source file seen by Scons, from within the Sconscript file. This works, but has an issue - it's pretty slow because it doesn't take advantage of the Scons compilation cache.

How would you recommend to integrate a custom preprocessing step into SCons build system, in a way that the compilation cache is used? Obviously I also need proper #include dependencies scanning, parallel compilation etc. I'm not very experienced with SCons, so I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

My current two areas of research are:

- Finding some way to invoke the put/retrieve cache functions manually, but this is risky - I don't want to pollute the cache with invalid entries.
- Creating a custom tool/pseudobuilder/something, that would allow me to execute two commands. Or try to make scons use two tools/pseudobuilders. This seems complicated.
- Tom Tanner's answer, which seems to suffer from #include dependencies not being detected correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the scons cache you have to have a target. scons caches the target based on the contributing files and build command.

Even without a builder, you can write yourself a Command processor a bit like this.

```
out_cc = env.Command('file.wave.cpp', 'file.cpp', 'wave command < $SOURCE > $TARGET')
env.Program('myprog', ['this.cc', 'that.cc', out_cc])
```

This will use the cache.

You can add a builder if you like, so you can do that in all one step. Builders are nice for where you'll use the same command in multiple places or have more complex requirements than can be described with a simple Command. However, they aren't essential for the cache to work.

Edit: Updated to include liosan's solution for wave taking .cpp files and producing .cpp files and hence getting the include dependencies right. Desperate for reputation I am...

Comment: Looks promising, I'm looking into it. But how will SCons know that it's supposed to compile the preprocessed file?

Comment: Um, maybe I'm not reading it correctly, but after I applied your snippet into our build system I got an error along the lines of "I don't know what to do with "X.wave" file, unexpected extension 'wave'" ...

Comment: I actually used env.Command('out.cpp.wave', 'out.cpp', ...), so that explains it. I currently got your solution working by using env.Command('out.cpp.cpp', 'out.cpp', ...), which is acceptable if not perfect. Is there a way were I could make scons know that ".wave" files are just like ".cpp" files?

Comment: Unfortunately I discovered this solution doesn't detect implicit dependencies changed :( (meaning #include files). So it's useless (meaning needs more research).

Comment: well, if wave files have a cpp extension it's going to be rather difficult, admittedly. You'd  have to write a scanner (or at least tell SCons it needs to use the C-scanner on wave files).

Comment: I ended up with:
`out_cc = env.Command('file.wave.cpp', 'file.cpp', 'wave command < $SOURCE > $TARGET')`

The important things to note are: (a) Because the output file name is different that the input, SCons doesn't treat it as a dependency cycle; and (b) the file still ends in .cpp, which means dependency scanners and compilers are setup correctly. If you update your answer I'll mark it as accepted :)